# Comparing if 2 arraylists contain the same characters indexwise

Tags: java

I am trying to develop a quiz application in Java where the user enters the answer to a multiple-choice question. Right now, I have 2 array lists, one storing the correct answers to all the questions and the other storing the user's answers. In order to get the user's score for the quiz, I have to compare the individual characters in both the lists, and every time I see a common character at the same index, I increase the user's score by 1.

Here is the code:

```
ArrayList<String> userAnswers = storeCorrectAnswers();
ArrayList<String> correctAnswers = askQuestionsOneByOne();

int score = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < userAnswers.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < correctAnswers.size(); j++) {
        if (userAnswers.get(i) == correctAnswers.get(j)) {
            score++;
        }
    }
}
return score;
```

storeCorrectAnswers() and askQuestionsOnyByOne return arraylists.

Right now, I am trying to use a nested for loop but it is not working.

Can anyone suggest to me how to go about this?

Comment: Would you please share the code, what you have done so far?

Comment: Yes sure, I will add it to my question

Comment: You should use single loop to iterate over both the lists and compare items at the same index

Comment: Use just a normal for loop `for(int i = 0; i < answerList.size(); i++)` then compare by reading with index `if(answerList.get(i).equals(userAnswerList.get(i)) score++;`. A nested loop doesn't make sense in this case.

Comment: I am not able to implement that. I tried but I am got stuck because I couldn't figure out how to use 2 indices with one loop

Comment: when you use nested loop you are basically comparing every item from one list to another which is wrong as per problem description, the idea is compare item at the same index

Comment: @ernest_k That seems to be working, thanks a lot!

Comment: @YamanJain I realized my mistake, I was complicating it unnecessarily. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, if you had to compare each entire string in `userAnswers` with the one at the corresponding index in `correctAnswers`, you could have used a single `for` loop with a simple check like `userAnswers.get(i).equals(correctAnswers.get(i))`, but since you have to do another thing, as you said

> I have to compare the individual characters in both the lists, and every time I see a common character at the same index, I increase the user's score by 1.

you should do something different. You can use a nested `for` loop to cycle, in the first loop, through the entire answers and, in the second one, through the single characters. So, you could use something like this:

```java
ArrayList<String> userAnswers = storeCorrectAnswers();
ArrayList<String> correctAnswers = askQuestionsOneByOne();

public int getTotalScore()  {
    int score = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < userAnswers.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < userAnswers.get(i).length(); j++) {
            if (userAnswers.get(i).charAt(j) == correctAnswers.get(i).charAt(j)) {
                score++;
            }
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

N.B. I assume that `userAnswers` has the exact same size of `correctAnswers`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0;i<correctAnswers.size();i++)
{
 if(userAnswers[i]==correctAnswers[i])
      score++;
}
```

Single for loop is sufficient in this case. whenever correctAnswers character exhausts then it will come out of loop.`time complexity` would be `O(n)`

Answer (score -1):

You should use a single loop. There is no need for nested loops.

```java
for(int i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length(); i++){
  if(correntAnswers.get(i).equals(userAnswers.get(i)){
     score++;
  }
}
```

In addition, I would extract the if condition into a private method to incrase the readability.

```java
for(int i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length(); i++){
  if(isSame(correctAnsers.get(i), userAnswers.get(i)){
     score++;
  }
}


----
private boolean isSame(String correctAnswer, String userAnswer){
 return correntAnswer.equals(userAnswer);
// You could use toUpperCase for better matching
// In this solution "Apple" is not equal to "apple".
}
```

Comment: You are not doing what you have been required though, isn't it? You are not checking each character of the respective strings. A nested loop would be useful in this case